# Swift: Dynamic Object Creation

Tags: swift

I am trying to create objects dynamically based on the output of an XML file.  My apologies if there are other posts on this subject, I don't even know what this is called.  Basically I want to create a stack of objects that could be of any class.  In a nutshell, when the "didStartElement" of the NSXMLParser is called, I want to create an object of type "elementName" and stack it to my object stack.  The code below is not working, just trying to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.  Normally I would just put "objectStack.append(object) as object" but in this case I don't know what the object type is going to be until the element is scanned by the XML parser. I believe the NSClassFromString is the way to do this, but it's not working.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    objectStack.append(NSClassFromString(elementName))

}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Even if you can just point me in the right direction.

Comment: When you say its not working? Whats the error you are getting? I think you need to actually alloc & init the object, try `objectStack.append(NSClassFromString(elementName)())` note the extra `()`.

Comment: Just solved the issue, I was really close.  I just need to prepend the project name in front of the element name.  Working code to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, the problem was that I needed the fully qualified name of the class, with the project name.

Working code:

```
var objectStack = [AnyClass]()
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    var className = String(NSString(format: "MyProject.%@", elementName))
    objectStack.append(NSClassFromString(className)!)
}
```

Comment: Does this work for NSObject, AnyObject, Any, struct, and/or type aliases.

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried.  I only used this on NSObject.  My code has changed again to init the object.  I can post the updated code if you would like.